# Multiple XML tag value into single column with comma separator

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have an XML where the XML have multiple similar tag and I want this value need to show in one column with comma separator and insert into table.

For example:

```
<test xmlns="http://www.google.com">
<code>a</code>
<code>b</code>
<code>c</code>
</test>
```

Since XML is too large and I am using `OPENXML` to perform operation and insert that value into particular table.

I am performing like

```
insert into table A
(
    code
)
select Code from OPENXML(sometag)
with (
    code varchar(100) 'tagvalue'
)
```

for `XQUERY` I am using something like this: `'for $i in x:Code return concat($i/text()[1], ";")'` and I want same with `OPENXML`.

Output: I want code tag value into one column like a,b,c or a/b/c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And just for completeness, here is method #3 via pure XQuery and FLWOR expression.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata xml);

INSERT @tbl (xmldata) VALUES
('<test  xmlns="http://www.google.com"><code>a</code><code>b</code><code>c</code></test>'),
('<test  xmlns="http://www.google.com"><code>d</code><code>e</code><code>f</code></test>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = ',';

-- Method #3
-- SQL Server 2005 onwards
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://www.google.com')
SELECT ID
   , xmldata.query('for $i in /test/code
      return if ($i is (/test/code[last()])[1]) then string($i)
            else concat($i, sql:variable("@separator"))')
   .value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS [Comma_separated_list]
FROM @tbl;
```

> Output

```
+----+----------------------+
| ID | Comma_separated_list |
+----+----------------------+
|  1 | a, b, c              |
|  2 | d, e, f              |
+----+----------------------+
```

Comment: xml have namespace also i am taking that with XMLNAMESPACE but still i am not getting data at output. @Yitzhak Khabinsky

Comment: @suraj, Please update your original post with namespaces. And I will adjust my answer accordingly.

Comment: i more thing if you could help me... i have large xml what i posted is one tag when i used XQUERY to parse data and insert into particular table it takes very much time. So i used OPENXML to make it works but for this tag i am not getting data as multiple. @Yitzhak Khabinsky

Comment: I updated the answer to handle a default namespace.

Comment: @suraj, Please mark this post as Answered. And open another thread to cover your real large XML, and real process.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're on SQL Server 2017 you could use [STRING_AGG (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql) to concatenate your code values, e.g.:

```sql
create table dbo.Test (
  someTag xml
);

insert dbo.Test (someTag) values
  ('<test><code>a</code><code>b</code><code>c</code></test>'),
  ('<test><code>d</code><code>e</code><code>f</code></test>');

select [Code], [someTag]
from dbo.Test
outer apply (
  select [Code] = string_agg([value], N',')
  from (
    select n1.c1.value('.', 'nvarchar(100)')
    from someTag.nodes(N'/test/code') n1(c1)
  ) src (value)
) a1;
```

Which yields...

```
Code    someTag
a,b,c   <test><code>a</code><code>b</code><code>c</code></test>
d,e,f   <test><code>d</code><code>e</code><code>f</code></test>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a small tweak to **AlwaysLearning (+1)**

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,XMLData xml)
insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'<test><code>a</code><code>b</code><code>c</code></test>')

Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
               Select DelimString = string_agg(xAttr.value('.','varchar(max)'),',')
                From  A.XMLData.nodes('/test/*') xNode(xAttr)
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
ID  DelimString
1   a,b,c
```

Comment: Good answer, +1 from my side! It would be even faster with one additional tweak: `.value('(./text())[1]', ...`